# How bitwise or and not operator works?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a, b, c;
  a=5;
  b=8;
  c= ~(a|b);
  printf("%d",c);
}
```

The expected the output is  `-13` but the results shows  `-14`. How is it `- 14`? .

Comment: Greetings! Open calc.exe on Windows or something similar and try for yourself.
`5 | 8 == 13` but then you use `~`, a negation. So `~ 13 == 14`, looks fine, as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a 2's complement computer.

- 5 | 8 gives binary `0101 | 1000 = 1101` = 13 dec.
- Invert this with `~` and you get `1111....0010`.
- Representing that as a signed type, then in 1's complement this would have been -13 dec.
- But for 2's complement we subtract 1 and get -14 dec.

For the same reason as `~0` gives 2's complement `-1` and not `-0`.

Answer (score 0):

you confuse the complement to one (~) and the complement to two / unary operator -

`~(5|8)` is `-(5|8) - 1` so `-13 - 1` so -14

Answer (score 0):

This is due to two's complement representation of negative numbers.  Two's complement is performed by inverting all bits then adding one.

First, you have `a|b` (for simplicity's sake I'll show only the low order 8 bits):

```
  a  00000101  5
| b  00001000  8
 ------------
     00001101  13
```

Then the bitwise NOT:

```
   ~ 00001101  13
   ----------
     11110010  -14
```

Performing a bitwise NOT on a positive value does not give you its negative value, it gives you one *less*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you use 8-bit integers:

- `a=5` is represented as `00000101`
- `b=8` is represented as `00001000`
- `a|b` is `00001101`

When you invert the bits, it will be `11110010`, which in [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is `-14`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of 2's complement.

Using 8 bit signed values (it works the same with 32 bit signed, but this is easier to demonstrate):

```
8:        00001000
5:        00000101
8 | 5:    00001101
~(8 | 5): 11110010 = 242 (unsigned)
```

Quick way to do 2's complement when the MSb is high is to subtract 2^n  (here n is 8, 2^8 is 256)

242-256=-14